# Could not put the class dragme items in horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Could not put the class dragme items in horizontal scroll.They are appearing vertically

Here is my code

```
.dragme
    {
        border: 5px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px;
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 430px;
       overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 50px;
white-space:nowrap
    }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this:-

Add this class

```
.ui-draggable{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
```

}

**[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/13/)**

Comment: If I drag and drop a 20 images into the dropme panel then it over flows the box.Is there a way to make the dropme panel expandable

Comment: Then you can make the make overflow:auto or remove float:left.

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar is frozen or dead http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/18/show/

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` in class `ui-draggable`

```
.ui-draggable{
    float: left;  
    padding: 2px; /* to make space bw the images */
}
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/1xnmtyqs/15/)**

Comment: If I drag and drop a 20 images into the dropme panel then it over flows  the box.Is there a way to make the dropme panel expandable

Comment: So you wanna fix it in single row?

Comment: I want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/h41zjspc/  If i drag and drop the images then the panel expands as the drag and drop of  images increase